# PHP formatting list items

Tags: php, text-formatting

I want to convert following text into list items

```
* Item 1
* Item 2

- item 1
- item 2
```

to

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

I have made following regex which is not good enough for this

```
$text = preg_replace('#(*\s[*.]\s*)#','<li>$0</li>', $text);
```

but that does not work. I am not good at making RE.

I am making question more clear here.

A text may contain bullets or may not and I cant loop through the file as atno suggested.

Here are the samples

```
* HTML *SEO * Javascript * PHP

- HTML
- SEO
-Javascript
-PHP

-HTML - SEO -Javascript -PHP
```

Comment: no text from database. Its user entered text.

Comment: are you trying to create a markdown system like stackoverflow and github use ?

Comment: Why not support a complete markup language, like Markdown, and let a parser do the job for you?

Comment: @jason show us a bit more code, how does the text you're retrieving from the database looks like

Comment: @atno: That's not really relevant. All the information you need to know is in the question.

Comment: @tim if that's the case then jason you could surround his records with `<li></li>`  on a foreach or while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little nasty to do with regular expressions, but here you go:

```
<?php
$text = <<<TEXT
* HTML *SEO * Javascript * PHP

- HTML
- SEO
-Javascript
-PHP

-HTML - SEO -Javascript -PHP
TEXT;

$text = preg_replace_callback('`([*-]\s*([^*-\r\n]+)(\r?\n)?)+`', function($m) {
    $str = '<ul>';
    $str .= preg_replace('`[*-]\s*([^*-\r\n]+)\s*`', '<li>$1</li>', $m[0]);
    $str .= '</ul>';
    return $str;
}, $text);

echo $text;
```

I get this as output:

*snip* clarification changes output

Comment: This is the best solution, however I am still trying to make it perfect. I am trying to convert only those list items which are more than one for example *a *b - c *d - e * f * g in this case a and b will be converted into list items and f and g only. I have written following RE #(\*\s*([^*\r\n]+)([*\r\n\*]))# This works fine except it does not work for last item say g.

Comment: oh, I was assuming you didn't want to mix list types. I deliberately did it this way so they'd be converted to separate lists, and blank lines in between would also end the list. should be able to replace the `\*` with `[*-]` instead in the first block (it's in there twice) and then just scrap the second part. here..i'll edit, but cant test here

Answer (score 2):

So maybe something along the lines of:

```
<?PHP
$text = <<<Text
* HTML *SEO * Javascript * PHP

- HTML
- SEO
-Javascript
-PHP

-HTML - SEO -Javascript -PHP
Text;

$text = preg_replace('/(\*|-)\s*([\S]+)\s*/',"<li>$2</li>\n",$text);

print $text;
?>
```

which gives an output of:

```
<li>HTML</li>
<li>SEO</li>
<li>Javascript</li>
<li>PHP</li>
<li>HTML</li>
<li>SEO</li>
<li>Javascript</li>
<li>PHP</li>
<li>HTML</li>
<li>SEO</li>
<li>Javascript</li>
<li>PHP</li>
```

Comment: +1 for you, i was about to paste my solution but i wasn't using preg_replace as i'm not familiar with

Comment: we still need to sort out <ul></ul>

Comment: @jason, where do you want the <ul>'s, I was presuming they'd just be at the start and end!

Comment: these list items can be anywhere in the text or it may not be at all

Answer (score 0):

ok this is the best i can come up with but it solve part of the problem, maybe someone else can find a better

```
// first i remove the spaces after the hyphen, like in '- SEO' to have some consistency 
$str = str_replace ('- ','-', $str); 

// then i look for hyphen-word-new line  and replace it with the format i want.
$list = preg_replace('#\-(.*)\n#',"<li>$1</li>\n", $str);
```

Obviously this will not be completely correct because you still need the `<ul>` tag. so good luck!